# Typescript: interface containing an overloaded function cannot assign to itself

Tags: typescript, typeerror, overloading, union-types

I have an interface which looks like this:

```
interface RequestContext {
    createSubRequest(args: A): RequestContext;
    createSubRequest(args: B): Promise<RequestContext>;
    createSubRequest(args: A | B): RequestContext | Promise<RequestContext>
}
```

This interface is being used in an abstract class, like so:

```
abstract class JobManager {
    abstract getManager(ctx: RequestContext, job: Job): Promise<TaskManager>;
}
```

I am trying to implement this abstract function in my code. RequestContext, JobManager, and my code all lie in separate packages.

```
class MyJobManager extends JobManager {
    getManager(ctx: RequestContext, job: JobModule.Job) {
```

I get a type error here telling me parameters "ctx" and "ctx" are incompatible. Upon digging deeper, the full error message looks like this:

```
 Types of property 'createSubRequest' are incompatible.
      Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
        Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
```

It appears to be getting mixed up and trying to assign different versions of the same overloaded function to each other. I can't find any other thread that addresses my situation.

For additional context, the types look like this:

```
interface A extends BaseSubRequestArguments {
    envOvr?: undefined;
}
interface B extends BaseSubRequestArguments {
    envOvr: string;
}
```

And the full type error ends with this:

```
Types of property 'envOvr' are incompatible.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)
```

I tried commenting out the first 2 versions of createSubRequest, leaving only the signature with union types, but the error didn't go away.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://tsplay.dev/mLvkvw. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the errors you are describing.